# Prove that there exist infinitely many solutions of IVP

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that:$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and for some $x_0]in \mathbb{R}$ there exist two distinct solutions to the problem $x'=f(x), x(0)=x_0$ for $0\le t \le 1$. Prove that there exist infinitely many solutions to this problem valid in an interval of the form $[0,a]$ for some $a>0$. I have tried to use Picard iteration but I don't know how to go to further. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: what is $f(x_0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $f(x_0)=0$, otherwise the method of separation of variables would have guaranteed the unicity of solution of the Cauchy problem $$x'=f(x),\quad x(0)=x_0.$$

Therefore, one of the solutions of that system is non-constant; we will call it $\bar x(t)$. Also, a constant $x_0$ is also a solution of that system.

Now for $s>0$ take a function $$x_s(t) = \begin{cases} x_0, & t\in[0,s]\\\bar x(t-s),&t>s.\end{cases}$$

This is obviously a solution of the initial system, and for different $s$ the functions $x_s$ are distinct, hence we have an infinite family of solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.